# Matplotlib into a Django Template

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

Im using python 3.4 and Django 1.8. I want to "print" a matplotlib result in a Django template. I reach this a few days ago, so I continue in other things of my Django App. Now, I dont know why, I was going to show the result to a friend, and my template with a matplotlib graph, now shows a big code! I dont know why this happen, because my view doesnt change in anything from when it was showing the right graph! Please help me!

This is my view!

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from matplotlib import pylab
from pylab import *
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import io
from io import *

def graphic(request):

pos = arange(10)+ 2 

barh(pos,(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),align = 'center')

yticks(pos,('#hcsm','#ukmedlibs','#ImmunoChat','#HCLDR','#ICTD2015','#hpmglobal','#BRCA','#BCSM','#BTSM','#OTalk'))

xlabel('Popularity')
ylabel('Hashtags')
title('Hashtags')
subplots_adjust(left=0.21)

buffer = io.BytesIO()
canvas = pylab.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
canvas.draw()
graphIMG = PIL.Image.fromstring('RGB', canvas.get_width_height(),               canvas.tostring_rgb())
graphIMG.save(buffer, "PNG")
content_type="Image/png"
buffercontent=buffer.getvalue()


graphic = (buffercontent ,content_type)
pylab.close()


return render(request, 'graphic.html',{'graphic':graphic})
```

Of course in my graphic.html is a variable called {{graphic}} inside a blockcontent!

This was showing the right result in my template! What happen?
Now sometimes when i run my template it shows a big code, or just show me this django error:

Exception Value:
main thread is not in main loop

Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py in blit, line 17

Help!

Comment: Try `{{ graphic | safe }}`

Comment: @lanAuld I make that change in my html template and it doesnt fix the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
    from io import BytesIO
    import base64
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    def graphic(request):

        pos = np.arange(10)+ 2 

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        ax.barh(pos, np.arange(1, 11), align='center')
        ax.set_yticks(pos)
        ax.set_yticklabels(('#hcsm',
            '#ukmedlibs',
            '#ImmunoChat',
            '#HCLDR',
            '#ICTD2015',
            '#hpmglobal',
            '#BRCA',
            '#BCSM',
            '#BTSM',
            '#OTalk',), 
            fontsize=15)
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.invert_yaxis()

        ax.set_xlabel('Popularity')
        ax.set_ylabel('Hashtags')
        ax.set_title('Hashtags')

        plt.tight_layout()

        buffer = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buffer, format='png')
        buffer.seek(0)
        image_png = buffer.getvalue()
        buffer.close()

        graphic = base64.b64encode(image_png)
        graphic = graphic.decode('utf-8')

        return render(request, 'graphic.html',{'graphic':graphic})
```

and in the template:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ graphic|safe }}">
```

I have:

matplotlib==3.0.2 and Django==2.1.4

Answer (score 6):

Edit:

try with

```
graphic = cStringIO.StringIO()
canvas.print_png(graphic)
return render(request, 'graphic.html',{'graphic':graphic})
```

You have to specify that your image is a binary string:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{graphic|safe}}">
```

Or actually save it to the filesystem and provide the path.

Alternatively you could use [Bokeh](http://bokeh.org) which can give you the html + javascript to embed the plot directly in the template, then it is dynamically generated and brings nice features.

Comment: I try to use:
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{graphic|safe}}"> 
and now i only get a broken image icon in my template! Im new in python, so i dont know i need to change in my view the render line to:

return render(request, 'graphic.html',{'graphic|safe':graphic})

Comment: the |safe function is meant to be in the template :) Can you add the image html code in you answer please?

Comment: {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
 

{% block subtitle %}<H2>blablabla</H2>{% endblock %} 

{% block graphic  %}
<img src="data:image/PNG;base64,{{graphic|safe}}">
{% endblock %}

Comment: When my code stops working, i was working in the settings of django static files, does this could be the reason of my problem?

Comment: ah ok, so you were saving it to the filesystem before. So yes you could also save it somewhere and make sure the directory is in the static files path. Or checkout my edit to display it inline.

Comment: I have been trying and stills don;t work! Do you have an idea of why it worked for a couple of days and now it doesnt work?

Comment: What was the content of graphic before? A path to a file? Or a binary string?

Comment: I see your edited answer and i see that you use StringIO, i have read here https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html that StringIO an cStringIO have gone!

Comment: When I was working for the first time, that big code that appears now, appeared to me! So I make this:

buffer = io.BytesIO()
    canvas = pylab.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
    canvas.draw()
    graphIMG = PIL.Image.fromstring('RGB', canvas.get_width_height(),               canvas.tostring_rgb())
    graphIMG.save(buffer, "PNG")
    content_type="Image/png"
    buffercontent=buffer.getvalue()


    graphic = (buffercontent ,content_type)

Comment: Can you send a http://pastebin.com/ with the binary string you get from you original code?

Comment: When I run my template, this is my graphic result: http://pastebin.com/mp3chFT8 This happens to me also when I start but I fix it with the code of my original post, but today it stop working and show me that again!

Comment: try: return render(request, 'graphic.html',{'graphic':graphic[0]}) and the inline image html code. Because graphic is a tuple, not just the string

Comment: That was exactly what I think when I make my original solution! Thats what i create a variable called graphic that contains the tuple of the buffer(binary string) and the content type! Anyway! This is how my code looks with you last comment advice http://www.pastebin.ca/3012993.
And here is the html: http://www.pastebin.ca/3012996

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/3012997 This code view, returns a new page with only the graphic and it looks nice...I need the result of this view in a template! So what i did, was to put this into a variable, (buffer.getvalue(), content_type="Image/png"), and put that variable into my template. That was working, i dont know what happen! And know I have to run my server a lot of times because it falls down showing me the error: the main thread is not in the main loop

Comment: Well then it is easy just point the image to it <img src="/graphico(or whatever the url of the view is)">

Comment: Thank you Maresh! A big hug from Costa Rica!

Answer (score 3):

The final solution was to create a special view that returns the matplotlib plot in an empty template, like this:

```
def grafico (rquest):
    pos = arange(10)+ 2 

    barh(pos,(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),align = 'center')

    yticks(pos,('#hcsm','#ukmedlibs','#ImmunoChat','#HCLDR','#ICTD2015','#hpmglobal','#BRCA','#BCSM','#BTSM','#OTalk'))

    xlabel('Popularidad')
    ylabel('Hashtags')
    title('Gráfico de Hashtags')
    subplots_adjust(left=0.21)

    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    canvas = pylab.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
    canvas.draw()
    graphIMG = PIL.Image.fromstring('RGB', canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
    graphIMG.save(buffer, "PNG")
    pylab.close()

    return HttpResponse (buffer.getvalue(), content_type="Image/png")
```

The next step is to put in your template this:

```
<img src="url_of_the_graphic_view">
```

And thats all!

Comment: That way you can show only 1 plot per page... right? :(

Answer (score 1):

```
def show(request):

x = np.arange(10)
y = x
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
canvas = fig.canvas
buf, size = canvas.print_to_buffer()
image = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', size, buf, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
buffer=io.BytesIO()
image.save(buffer,'PNG')
graphic = buffer.getvalue()
graphic = base64.b64encode(graphic)
buffer.close()
return render(request, 'graphic.html',{'graphic':graphic})
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: sorry. try with "graphic = base64.b64encode(graphic)",encode graphic in base64.  then the PNG can decoded in templates.

Answer (score 1):

I had a broken icon image as well, after using the answers above, and I fixed it by removing the `b'` and `'` from the graphic base64 binary representation :

`return render(request, 'graphic.html', {'graphic': str(graphic)[2:-1]})`