# django - temporarily storing figures

Tags: python, django, static-files

I have a database with population data. I want to create a page that shows a figure of this data (with for example matplotlib). How and where would I store the figures which I create with matplotlib?

Example data:

```
year | people
2010 | 100
2011 | 110
2012 | 110
2013 | 114
2014 | 124
2015 | 154
2016 | 143
2017 | 112
```

In my view I already have collected the variable, year and people. I would normally do something like this:

```
plt.plot(year, people)
plt.savefig('figure.svg')
```

The question is where/how would I store this and present it to the user? Should I store this in a media directory? I do not want to store the file forever cause then diskspace would quickly fill up with graphs which are only used once.

Comment: you can use matplotlib with django https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531990/matplotlib-into-a-django-template.  anyway, why not store it in a db

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the images in cache. Look at [django-sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail) for how to try that.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

One is to store figures under a specific folder inside the static folder you configured. (Have in mind that django has a good solution for public assets and you can configure your webserver to directly serve those files).
 Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2451739/5476782) question about serving those files using nginx.

Having this config in settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR) + '/static/'
```

It is possible to access files stored in:

```
/static/figures

http://your.domain.com/static/figures/figure.svg
```

In case that is not enough, use any Object Storage provider, here there are few of them:

- Amazon [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)
- Dreamhost
  [objects](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214823108-What-is-DreamObjects-)
- Rackspace [cloud files](https://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files)

Have a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) django documentation on static files deployment. It is very helpful.