# How to pass matplotlib graph in django template?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I am trying to pass a matplotlib graph in Django template. in views.py file using analyze function, I have created a graph. Then i have passed this graph to my Django template. But nothing shows up in my Django template except `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000001E39AB94F98>]`. How can i fix this?

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout
from diabetes.forms import UserSignupForm,UserLoginForm,MeasurementsForm
from diabetes.models import Measurements
import pandas as pd
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def analyze(request):

    qs=Measurements.objects.all().values()
    data=pd.DataFrame(qs)

    img=plt.plot(data.loc[:,'created'],data.loc[:,'d_value'])

    return render(request,'diabetes/analyze.html',{'df':img})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repeat - this question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531990/matplotlib-into-a-django-template)

Basically, you'll need to save your image as a file (e.g. png)

```
buffer = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buffer, format='png')
buffer.seek(0)
image_png = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()

graphic = base64.b64encode(image_png)
graphic = graphic.decode('utf-8')

return render(request, 'graphic.html',{'graphic':graphic})
```

and then use that image in your template:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ graphic|safe }}">
```

Comment: i have used this method but this time only a image icon apperas in the templat.

Comment: @imtinan If you inspect the rendered HTML what do you see in the image tag?

Comment: <img src="data:image/png;base64,"> this shows in the imag tag

Comment: When you run `plt.savefig()` can you find where that image is saved in your file system?

Comment: after running the file i have found no image saved in my app. For your information i have no static folder in app.

Comment: problem solved i was using wrong key! thanks @ Eric.